# Dynamic folder path change in Power BI using Report page

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Is there a possibility to have something similar like in Excel, where you have a drop down list on workbook then you choose specific folder, click refresh button and there you go...I mean there is parameter option in Power BI which is fine, but is there an option or some tweak or else, where you can have that drop down list (those parameters) visible on report page in Power BI, so I can simply and quickly choose certain folder and get the data?

I didn't upload any pictures, I guess it is quite understandable.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way for the report author to change the folder path in a fixed PQ is through parameters.

In order for you to choose different folder paths from a list of paths would be authoring the parameter table with `List of Values` and select a single value as the `Default value` and/or `current value`.

When you load the query, it gets loaded with default path and when you need the query to be loaded data from a different folder, you can do home -> Edit Parameters and the drop down would be available to you.

Once you select a different path on the drop down, you need to refresh all the queries to have up-to-date data reflected.